# Set draggable items with have the same prefix class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a question in here and know how to select multi class start with "foo-class-", and get 2 ways to do this:

CASE 1: When you have the single class for a element

```
var $class = $('[class^="foo-class-"]');
```

CASE 2: When you have multiple classes for a element (Credit to Adeneo)

```
var $class = $('[class]').filter(function(){
    return (" " + this.className).indexOf(' foo-class-') != -1;
});
```

But I don't know how to apply this to a accept class draggable in jQueryUI, I also created codes here: http://jsfiddle.net/mQYF4/ but it don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with your selector, it was with your use of the `z-index` property of `draggable`.

In your jsfiddle, you had

```
dra.draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    z - index: 5
});
```

Change the z-index property to:

```
"z-index": 5
```

And this will work - [see it in my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamh/mQYF4/1/)

Comment: Thank, but the alert message box didnt appear, this mean the drop function dont work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're saying but if you're just trying to make them draggable, here you go:

```
<div class='draggable'></div>
<div class='draggable'></div>
<div class='draggable'></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQYF4/2/

You need to give them different ids and then select by class. The point of an id is to be distinct, and if there are duplicates jQuery will just select the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

replase yout `z - index: 5` with `z - index: 5`

doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-zIndex